# phonegap-appgyver mobile app - redirect back to app from outside?

Tags: mobile, cordova, steroids

I am playing with Appgyver - Steroids app and i think in the context of question is no differ from Phonegap.

Is somehow possible to visit external url which perform redirection back to app?

Like

```
<a href="http://redirect.me.back?target=http://localhost/tutorial.html">CLICK</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can redirect back to your app..

On your server just do something like this:

```
<a href="http://localhost/tutorial.html">Back to App</a>
```

Or use a redirection service back to the URL. eg bit.ly 
(or preferably your own page you have control over)

Comment: of course, this link will only work from inside your app, and shouldn't be shown to web visitors..